# Quotation issues reading data into R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I have some data from and I am trying to load it into **R**.  It is in .csv files and I can view the data in both Excel and OpenOffice.  (If you are curious, it is the 2011 poll results data from Elections Canada data available [here](http://www.elections.ca/scripts/resval/ovr_41ge.asp?prov=&lang=e)).

The data is coded in an unusual manner.  A typical line is:

```
12002,Central Nova","Nova-Centre"," 1","River John",N,N,"",1,299,"Chisholm","","Matthew","Green Party","Parti Vert",N,N,11
```

There is a `"` on the end of the Central-Nova but not at the beginning.  So in order to read in the data, I suppressed the quotes, which worked fine for the first few files. ie.

```
test<-read.csv("pollresults_resultatsbureau11001.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",",fileEncoding="latin1",as.is=TRUE,quote="")
```

Now here is the problem: in another file (eg. pollresults_resultatsbureau12002.csv), there is a line of data like this:

```
12002,Central Nova","Nova-Centre"," 6-1","Pictou, Subd. A",N,N,"",0,168,"Parker","","David K.","NDP-New Democratic Party","NPD-Nouveau Parti democratique",N,N,28
```

Because I need to suppress the quotes, the entry `"Pictou, Subd. A"` makes **R** wants to split this into 2 variables. The data can't be read in since it wants to add a column half way through constructing the dataframe.

Excel and OpenOffice both can open these files no problem.  Somehow, Excel and OpenOffice know that quotation marks *only matter if they are at the beginning of a variable entry*.

Do you know what option I need to enable on **R** to get this data in?  I have >300 files that I need to load (each with ~1000 rows each) so a manual fix is not an option...

I have looked all over the place for a solution but can't find one.

Comment: Some sort of regex solution to repair the unmatched quotes is probably one option. Probably lots of ways to go about that, but one R option might be to use `readLines`, replace ",[letters or spaces]"" with a fixed version using back references, push back out using `writeLines`...?

Comment: another thought, if the 300+ files are all the same format, would be to get them concatenated so you can operate on one file

Comment: You say "to suppress the quotes, the entry "Pictou, Subd. A" makes R wants to split this into 2 variables", it splits because you have a comma as a separator.

Comment: When did you download the files? There's a note at the bottom of the page that reads "Note that a formatting error was corrected on December 22, 2011, in the CSV files (format: pollresults-resultatsbureau).", and none of the files I have randomly chosen seem to have any problems. Can you link to the specific file that is giving you this problem?

Comment: @kpierce8, That is what I was planning on doing.  The way I was going to do this was using do.call("rbind"...).  Before that, however, I will need to be able to read them in.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I downloaded these files using the .zip provided today.  Looking at the metadata, it appears that these files (in the zip) were created in August 2011 (before the correction).
If I download the files individually then they are fine!

This, however, doesn't deal with the issue that I might need to now download all the files separately.

Comment: Here is the download for the zip [link](http://www.elections.ca/scripts/OVR2011/34/data_donnees/pollresults_resultatsbureau_canada.zip)

All these files should have the mistake noted by @AnandaMahto.

Comment: Surely concatenating the files is a simple one-liner using `cat` from a linux/osx command line, no?

Comment: @joran Perhaps that might be the case, however, I am unsure whether that would help deal with reading in the data.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Just called elections Canada: they will fix the file link in a few days.  In the mean time, I will just download the data at the provincial level (10 zip files).  So problem solved!

Comment: @JaM, great. I wonder if something like the following would work (though it is probably inefficient): `temp <- readLines("pollresults_resultatsbureau11001.csv"); temp[-1] <- gsub('^(.{6})(.*)$', '\\1\\"\\2', temp[-1]); read.csv(text = temp...`. The `gsub` will insert a quotation mark after the sixth position of each line except the header line (assuming all the codes are 5 digits, and then a comma, that should work). Not tested, but try it out just for fun!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, fantastic -- I'll give it a try.  Also, a friend who works a lot with R sent me:
Look at `scan()`
I think you'll need  
`raw = scan(file = file.csv, what = '', sep = '\n')`
This will read each line into character vector of the same length as the number of rows in the file

Then to access the particular element that you want / or convert it to a matrix you need to use the function
`strsplit` or `splitstr` (can't remember which way)
`strsplit(raw[1], split = ',')`
And you can build a function using this method to split on " , or ","

Comment: Did all my work on the 2011 and 2006 election data but it seems that the 2008 election data also suffers from the same problem.  The issue with your solution @AnandaMahto is that it might be very labour intensive -- the first entry changes quite significantly.  I'll try the posted answer and update the thread if it works.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I just implemented your solution.  I was wrong in my previous comment: the codes *are* all 5 digits long.  I have written up a simple answer and posted it.  I don't know how to properly credit you with this answer though -- is there a more formal way to link to your contribution/profile?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Ah sorry - new to this.  Should I "accept" the one that worked for me or the best one?  I am unsure of the etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on my comments, here is a solution that would read *all* the CSV files into a single list.

```
# Deal with French properly
options(encoding="latin1")

# Set your working directory to where you have
#   unzipped all of your 308 CSV files
setwd("path/to/unzipped/files")

# Get the file names
temp <- list.files()

# Extract the 5-digit code which we can use as names
Codes <- gsub("pollresults_resultatsbureau|.csv", "", temp)

# Read all the files into a single list named "pollResults"
pollResults <- lapply(seq_along(temp), function(x) {
  T0 <- readLines(temp[x])
  T0[-1] <- gsub('^(.{6})(.*)$', '\\1\\"\\2', T0[-1])
  final <- read.csv(text = T0, header = TRUE)
  final
})
names(pollResults) <- Codes
```

You can easily work with this list in different ways. If you wanted to just see the 90th `data.frame` you can access it by using `pollResults[[90]]` or by using `pollResults[["24058"]]` (in other words, either by index number or by district number).

Having the data in this format means you can also do a lot of other convenient things. For instance, if you wanted to fix all 308 of the CSVs in one go, you can use the following code, which will create new CSVs with the file name prefixed with "Corrected_".

```
invisible(lapply(seq_along(pollResults), function(x) {
  NewFilename <- paste("Corrected", temp[x], sep = "_")
  write.csv(pollResults[[x]], file = NewFilename, 
            quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
}))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mainly to @AnandaMahto (see comments to the original question).

First, it helps to set some options globally because of the french accents in the data:

```
options(encoding="latin1")
```

Next, read in the data verbatim using `readLines()`:

`temp <- readLines("pollresults_resultatsbureau13001.csv")`

Following this, simply replace the first comma in each line of data with a comma+quotation.  This works because the first field is always 5 characters long.  Note that it leaves the header untouched.

`temp[-1] <- gsub('^(.{6})(.*)$', '\\1\\"\\2', temp[-1])`

Penultimately, write over the original file.

`fileConn<-file("pollresults_resultatsbureau13001.csv")`
`writeLines(temp,fileConn)`
`close(fileConn)`

Finally, simply read the data back into R:

`data<-read.csv(file="pollresults_resultatsbureau13001.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",")`

There is probably a more parsimonious way to do this (and one that can be iterated more easily) but this process made sense to me.

Comment: Great! +1 for taking the efforts to get this to work. I'm glad the comments helped. I've added a more streamlined solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15093849/1270695), but I'm not sure how comfortable you are with dealing with `list`s. I would personally prefer have a single list in my workspace to hundreds of objects. And, since these `data.frame`s are all the same format, you can also use `do.call(rbind, pollResults)` (from my answer) to get one giant `data.frame` that includes all the districts in one place. Try it out and report back, and good luck with your analysis!