# Read csv with both paired and unpaired quotation marks

Tags: sql-server, regex, r, csv

I have a csv file generated from MS SQL Server that I am trying to read into R. It has data like the following:

```
# reproduce file
possibilities <- c('this is good','"this has, a comma"','here is a " quotation','')
newstrings <- expand.grid(possibilities,possibilities,possibilities,stringsAsFactors = F)
xwrite <- apply(newstrings,1,paste,collapse = ",")
xwrite <- c('v1,v2,v3',xwrite)
writeLines(xwrite,con = 'test.csv')
```

I would normally open this with Excel and it magically reads and writes it in a cleaner format for R, but this is over the row limit. If I can't figure it out, I'll have to go back and output it in another format. I tried a lot of variations I've read about.

```
# a few things I've tried
(rl <- readLines('test.csv'))
read.csv('test.csv',header = T,quote = "",stringsAsFactors = F)
read.csv('test.csv',header = F,quote = "",stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 1)
read.csv('test.csv',header = T,stringsAsFactors = F)
read.csv('test.csv',header = F,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 1)
read.table('test.csv',header = F)
read.table('test.csv',header = F,quote = "\"")
read.table('test.csv',header = T,sep = ",")
scan('test.csv',what = 'character')
scan('test.csv',what = 'character',sep = ",")
scan('test.csv',what = 'character',sep = ",",quote = "")
scan('test.csv',what = 'character',sep = ",",quote = "\"")

unlist(strsplit(rl,split = ','))
```

This seems to work on the data I have, but I am uneasy about reusing it as it does not work on the sixth row which illustrates data that could potentially happen in another file.

```
# works if only comma OR unpaired quotation but not both
rl[grep('^[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$',rl)] <- sub('^([^\"]*)(\")([^\"]*)$','\\1\\3',rl[grep('^[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$',rl)])
writeLines(rl,'testfixed.csv')
read.csv('testfixed.csv')
```

I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074872/quotation-issues-reading-data-into-r), but my quotation mark issue is a loner in the data, not a consistent format issue.

Is it possible to get a proper data.frame from this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there a direct way to do it.  Here I am basically using `strsplit` with a comma as a separator. But first , I treat the special separators like  `,\"` or `\",`.

```
lines <- readLines('test.csv')
## separate teh quotaion case
lines_spe <- strsplit(lines,',\"|\",')
nn <- sapply(lines_spe,length)==1
## the normal case
lines[nn] <- strsplit(lines[nn],',',perl=TRUE)
## aggregate the results
lines[!nn] <- lines_spe[!nn]
## bind to create a data.frame
dat <-
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lines[-1]),stringsAsFactors =F),
         lines[[1]])
## treat the special case of strsplit('some text without second part,',',')
dat[dat$v1==dat$v2,"v2"] <- ""
dat
#                         v1                      v2
# 1             this is good            this is fine
# 2       this has no commas      this has, a comma"
# 3   this has no quotations  this has a " quotation
# 4 this field has something                        
# 5                          now the other side does
# 6       "this has, a comma  this has a " quotation
# 7         and a final line     that should be fine
```

The result is nearly good except the case of not having a second part where `strsplit` fails to get the second empty text : In your data , this happens with :'this field has something,'. Here an example to explain the problem:

```
 strsplit('aaa,',',')
[[1]]
[1] "aaa"

> strsplit(',aaa',',')
[[1]]
[1] ""    "aaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much closer and will probably do. It will fail if a lone quotation mark is next to a comma, because I am assuming that those would be the start or end of a string that actually needs quoted.

```
rl <- readLines('test.csv')
rl <- gsub('([^,])(\")([^,])','\\1\\3',rl,perl = T)
writeLines(rl,'testfixed.csv')
read.csv('testfixed.csv')
```